# Why is my HTML file keeps saying file not accessed when trying to open a form link?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I created a button link for Contact Me (which I created another html file from the normal index file to show the form link) but when I click on it shows file not accessed. Why? And how can I fix it?

1. I checked the anchor tag
2. I checked the name of the file

Comment: What's the exact link that you pass? Can you share?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is hard to understand the reason unless you provide more details and your code. However, here are some suggestions:

Check the File Name and the path:
Your anchor element should be something like

```
<a href="contact.html">Contact Me</a>
```

If your file is in another directory, you should specify the correct path:

```
<a href="example/pages/contact.html">Contact Me</a>
```

**Local File Access:** If you are opening your files in your browser, such as `file:///` in the address bar, some browsers might restrict your access due to security reasons.

**Clearing Cache:** Sometimes, because of the cache, the application can work unexpectedly; try to clean them and refresh your page.

**Try a Different Browser:** The issue might be browser-specific; it might be a good idea to try on a different browser.

**File Encoding and BOM:** Make sure that your HTML file is saved with UTF-8 encoding without a BOM (Byte Order Mark). Some editors might add a BOM to UTF-8 files, which can cause issues like those you are facing in some web browsers.

**Check Console Errors:** Check if there is any broken HTML or JavaScript code in the console. In the event of any error, your file could be unaccessible. Moreover, if your file depends on external resources (CDNs, scripts, stylesheets, etc.), make sure that those links are also working fine